# Add a convert to comment for invalid edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

When I am regularly reviewing posts, I see edits which add useful information to the post such as code that could help a future reader or a comment. Unless it's vandalism, a lot of times this information is very helpful. I'd like to propose a feature that upon successful rejection of an invalid edit, the information in the invalid edit is converted into a comment (or multiple if it won't fit into the number of character limit). The comment wouldn't be by Community, but by the user who did the invalid edit.

I could copy the invalid edit and make it a comment myself, but I don't want to be held responsible for the edit/comment which I had nothing to do with in the first place.

Comment: While I like the idea, the implementation is a bit tricky. What should be included and what should not? How is it specified?

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's a comment so you get no points, I'd think the impact would be minimal.